# MySQL load data infile is executed but the table remained empty

Tags: mysql

So im trying to load a FAERS data in mysql with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `demo22q4`(
  `primaryid` INT NOT NULL,
  `caseid` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `caseversion` INT NOT NULL,
  `i_f_code` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  `event_dt` VARCHAR(20),
  `mfr_dt` VARCHAR(20),
  `init_fda_dt` VARCHAR(20),
  `fda_dt` VARCHAR(20),
  `rept_cod` VARCHAR(20),
  `auth_num` VARCHAR(20),
  `mfr_num` VARCHAR(100),
  `mfr_sndr` VARCHAR(100),
  `lit_ref` VARCHAR(100),
  `age` INT,
  `age_cod` VARCHAR(10),
  `age_grp` VARCHAR(5),
  `sex` VARCHAR(5),
  `e_sub` VARCHAR(5),
  `wt` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `wt_cod` VARCHAR(10),
  `rept_dt` VARCHAR(20),
  `to_mfr` VARCHAR(5),
  `occp_cod` VARCHAR(5),
  `reporter_country` VARCHAR(50),
  `occr_country` VARCHAR(50)
);
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\DEMO22Q4.txt'
INTO TABLE demo22q4
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "$"
LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n"
IGNORE 1 ROWS;

SELECT * FROM faersmedinfo.demo22q4;
```

when i tried to run it it returns no error and it said the LOAD DATA INFILE is succesful but when i checked the table it's still empty. I'm not sure what I did wrong, i've checked the data is not corrupted or broken in any way, seems like the fields and lines delimiter is correct too. If anyone knows what's going on here it would be very appreciated thanks :)

if it's needed i've aslo attached the link to the file:
https://fis.fda.gov/extensions/FPD-QDE-FAERS/FPD-QDE-FAERS.html
I used the ASCII format of the latest data (october-december 2022)

Edit 1: adding the first 3 row of the input file

Header
primaryid$caseid$caseversion$i_f_code$event_dt$mfr_dt$init_fda_dt$fda_dt$rept_cod$auth_num$mfr_num$mfr_sndr$lit_ref$age$age_cod$age_grp$sex$e_sub$wt$wt_cod$rept_dt$to_mfr$occp_cod$reporter_country$occr_country

row 1

100115733$10011573$3$F$20130801$20221118$20140314$20221123$EXP$$CA-MERCK-1403CAN005674$MERCK$$75$YR$$M$Y$58.05$KG$20221123$$HP$CA$CA

row 2

1002130537$10021305$37$F$20210415$20220928$20140319$20221005$EXP$$PHHY2014CA019281$NOVARTIS$$43$YR$$M$Y$$$20221005$$HP$CA$CA

row 3

100234223$10023422$3$F$20120301$20221003$20140320$20221007$EXP$$US-ROCHE-1362929$ROCHE$$67$YR$$F$Y$$$20221007$$LW$US$

Comment: Why do you specify a schema name `faersmedinfo` only for the `select`?

Comment: Please add a few lines of the input file to the question.(I don't want clutter on my pc)

Comment: Are any of the columns in the input file empty?

Comment: This is UNIX-style text. Adjust lines terminator.

Comment: @pascal it's just a basic query provided by the workbench because I used the GUI to show the table

Comment: @P.Salmon I've provided a sample in the post, I'm not quite sure there are over 400k of rows here, but I think none of the rows would be empty on all columns. However, some rows have some empty columns (but not all columns)

Comment: @Akina I'm sorry but could you clarify about how should I adjust the line terminator?

Comment: Unix-style line terminator is 1-byte char 0x0A rather than Windows-style text which uses 2-byte string 0x0D0A. You must use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`. But after this adjustment you need also take into account that your structure does not match the data file - some data fields which are mapped to integer column contains empty string value instead of zero or `\N` (which matches NULL value), and this incorrectness will fail the importing. I recommend you make all columns VARCHAR, and after the importing fix these problematic values then alter columns datatypes. Or use input preprocessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the ASC_NTS.pdf in the zip file it has details of the max lengths and data types. You can apply some [Input Preprocessing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-preprocessing) to change the empty strings to NULLs and then populate the *_dt fields as DATEs.

As pointed out by Akina, the file has Unix-style line terminations (`\n`) but your `LOAD DATA INFILE` is using Windows-style (`\r\n`). Changing:

```sql
LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n"

-- to

LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
```

fixes this first problem but then you get the first error due to type mismatch (depending on MySQL version and mode):

```
Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'wt' at row 2
```

This is because you cannot insert an empty string into an integer column (again, depending on server version and mode). At this point you can either change the column to a suitably sized `VARCHAR` and worry about correcting date types later, or you can *correct* the column data type and add some preprocessing to change the empty string (`''`) to a `NULL`.

After changing `wt` to `DECIMAL(14, 5)` and preprocessing the empty strings to `NULL`s, there are some more 1366 & 1265 errors to deal with:

```
Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'lit_ref' at row 6
Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'age' at row 6
Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'auth_num' at row 236
```

And then finally, the out of range error for primaryid:

```
Error Code: 1264. Out of range value for column 'primaryid' at row 178013
```

The value at line 178013 is `2148614312` but a signed int can hold a max value of only `2147483647`. Changing `primaryid` to `INT UNSIGNED` means we can take a value up to `4294967295`.

I opted to change the data types of the following fields to get the demo file to load without errors:

```
ALTER TABLE `demo22q4`
    MODIFY `primaryid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    MODIFY `auth_num` VARCHAR(70),
    MODIFY `lit_ref` VARCHAR(500),
    MODIFY `wt` DECIMAL(14, 5);
```

and I changed all the *_dt fields to DATE instead of VARCHAR(20):

```
ALTER TABLE `demo22q4`
    MODIFY `event_dt` DATE,
    MODIFY `mfr_dt` DATE,
    MODIFY `init_fda_dt` DATE,
    MODIFY `fda_dt` DATE,
    MODIFY `rept_dt` DATE;
```

This is the `LOAD DATA INFILE`:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\DEMO22Q4.txt'
INTO TABLE demo22q4 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "$"
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
IGNORE 1 ROWS
    (primaryid, caseid, caseversion, i_f_code, @event_dt, @mfr_dt, init_fda_dt, fda_dt, rept_cod, auth_num, mfr_num, mfr_sndr, lit_ref, @age, age_cod, age_grp, sex, e_sub, @wt, wt_cod, rept_dt, to_mfr, occp_cod, reporter_country, occr_country)
    SET
        event_dt = NULLIF(@event_dt, ''),
        mfr_dt = NULLIF(@mfr_dt, ''),
        age = NULLIF(@age, ''),
        wt = NULLIF(@wt, '');
```

You can also run `LOAD DATA INFILE` with `IGNORE` which causes errors to be downgraded to warnings and it will just *jam the data in*, but this leads to integer columns being populated with `0` instead of `NULL` for an empty string. And my pet hate, 0 value dates (`0000-00-00`).

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\DEMO22Q4.txt' IGNORE
INTO TABLE demo22q4 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "$"
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

And then you can [`SHOW WARNINGS;`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-warnings.html) to see the warnings generated by the previous statement.

Comment: can you point out where i did wrong? i tested ur query and it works, but I'm still not sure what caused my query to not load the data into the table.

Comment: ah I see, thankyou for the explanation! my other peers is using the old version of MySQL so they don't have these kind of problem. I see that the newest version is more specific about data type. I thought '' is equals to NULL, but turns out i was wrong. once again thankyou for the detailed explanation :)

Comment: It is not so much the version (unless running very old) but the sql_mode which controls how MySQL handles invalid input data. Read the section on [Column Value Assignment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-column-assignments) for a detailed explanation.